# Sql Server: Compare varchar type value in where clause doesn't return results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation, varchar

I have a SQL Server 2012 Web Edition within the AWS RDS database service. The collation is the default one: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

In one of the tables I have a column `MODIFIED_BY` of type `varchar(128)` - the column collation is default.

The usual values stored into this column are GUIDS with the exception of a few which are hard coded to `System`. As you can tell it's a table for storing the audit trail transactions where we store the id or `System` if modification was done as part of the migration.

Anyways - everything above was just the context. Now the weird problem:

I get no records if I run the following, although I should have:

```
select *
from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt
where lower(ltrim(rtrim(alt.MODIFIED_BY)))='system'
```

or

```
select *
from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt
where lower(ltrim(rtrim(alt.MODIFIED_BY)))=convert(varchar,'system')
```

or

```
select *
from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt
where lower(ltrim(rtrim(alt.MODIFIED_BY)))=convert(varchar(128),'system')
```

I get records if I run the following:

```
select *
from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt
where alt.MODIFIED_BY like '%System%'
```

or

```
select *
from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt
where lower(ltrim(rtrim(CAST(alt.MODIFIED_BY AS nvarchar(max)))))='system'
```

**UPDATE**
Here's the table create script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS](
    [AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTION_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DATABASE] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TABLE_NAME] [nvarchar](261) NOT NULL,
    [TABLE_SCHEMA] [nvarchar](261) NOT NULL,
    [AUDIT_ACTION_ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [HOST_NAME] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [APP_NAME] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_BY] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AFFECTED_ROWS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SYSOBJ_ID]  AS (object_id([TABLE_NAME])),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTION_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS] ADD  DEFAULT (db_name()) FOR [DATABASE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS_MODIFIED_BY]  DEFAULT ('System') FOR [MODIFIED_BY]
GO
```

Comment: Sound like you may have some char values that are letter visible characters. You could add LEN(MODIFIED_BY) and easily determine id that is the case.

Comment: I'm confused about which of the queries above returns results. Can you groups the ones that work together, and the ones that don't work together? You say the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS - but is this the server collation, the database collation, or the collation of the `system` column? Can you validate that all three are the same? Can you generate a script for the table and post it to the question?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I've updated the problem with the create script and grouped the sql query results.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be there are some "hard to see" characters in your string ? 
To eliminate this possibility, I would run a query like this:

```
select alt.*, LEN(alt.MODIFIED_BY) as 'Length', cast(alt.MODIFIED_BY as varbinary(max)) as 'Bytes' from AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS alt where alt.MODIFIED_BY like '%System%'
```

Check that the Length and Bytes columns are what you expect to see.

Comment: Looks like the length returned is 64 but it should have been 6. The varbinary returned trailing zeros after the value `System` encoding. 
Kind of like this:
0x53797374656D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 

Why is that?

Comment: @user2417063 - Because that is what you must have inserted. I see this is an audit table. Is `MODIFIED_BY` populated by passing into the trigger the info in `CONTEXT_INFO`?

Comment: @MartinSmith - yes, it's coming through CONTEXT_INFO. So I guess I have to set the length of the varbinary variable used for CONTEXT_INFO to the actual length of the string, right?

Comment: @el_manolos - `CONTEXT_INFO` will always be padded out with trailing null bytes to length 128. Why is the length of your data 64? Are you only looking at the first half of it? Probably the easiest way would be to pad with trailing spaces yourself. `Declare @UserName BINARY(64) = CAST(CAST('System' AS CHAR(64)) AS BINARY(64)); SET CONTEXT_INFO @UserName; SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONTEXT_INFO(),1,64))`

Comment: @MartinSmith - this is how I declare it in code: "DECLARE \@BinVar varbinary(128) SET \@BinVar = CAST(N'{0}' AS varbinary(128)) SET CONTEXT_INFO \@BinVar".F(this.GetUserId())
But I assume returned length is 64 because maybe it uses two bytes to store the character, just a thought, not sure.

Comment: Yes you're passing it in as `nvarchar` but then storing it as `varchar`. But anyway just pad the string out to length 64 with trailing spaces. Then you can remove them easily with `RTRIM` before inserting.